# Правильно ли употребление: "всецело" в значении "всегда , во всём, полностью"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли употребление слова "всецело"?
Пример: Они всецело правы. (всегда, во всём, полностью) Или стоит подобрать другое слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Употребление правильно, но оно не охватывает значения "всегда". Если нужен такой смысл, то лучше "правы всегда и во всём".